# Can't see the free disk space of the drive

Tags: rhel, dual-boot

I am installing redhat 6 with pendrive, I get only two drives option for installing one is the whole hard disk and the other is pendrive, but I've created a free logical disk of 30 GB in windows. I am unable to view my other disks or the free disk as well.

Anyone please help

Answer (score 3):

If you have created a logical partition using windows, Wow that partition has some Microsoft partition type identifier and so it is unavailable to Linux.

Delete that partition using Windows and leave that space unpartitioned. Your Red-Hat installer will allow to partition it to suit Linux needs.